# oracle sql 'like' to find a specific substring

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

Using oracle sql, I want to find a text containing, for example, the exact word 'SAN' or its plural if any.
So my attempt was this:

```
select * 
from table a
where upper(a.text_field) like '%SAN%'
```

But one of the results from the query was any text containing 'san' such as:

```
artisan
partisan
```

But the desired results should be:

```
abcde san fgeft 
san abcde
abcde san(s) <- if there is a plural form
```

How do I find the exact word in a text in oracle sql?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer regexp, like this

```
select * 
from table a
where regexp_like(a.text_field,'\wsan\w', 'i')
```

`\w` - means word boundary, `i` - case unsensetive

But pure SQL could be with all word boundaries permutations, for example:

```
select * 
from table a
where upper(a.text_field) like '% SAN %' or upper(a.text_field) like 'SAN %' or upper(a.text_field) like '% SAN' --- and so on
```